# What should be the conditions which when fulfilled we can take something common out of a common exponent?

Tags: linear-algebra, exponentiation

Please see the image given below to understand what I am asking.If the image failed to make you understand what I am asking about, please tell me and I will try to help you out as much as I can
[image: The question with one example]

Comment: When it is defined (i.e. when $x\ne0$), it always hold, since $(ab)^n=a^nb^n.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Can you please elaborate.I failed to comprehend what you mean.

Comment: I mean that the answer to your question "under what conditions do we have this equality" is: there is no condition to fulfill, the equality is always true. Don't you know that $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ or can't you see why it entails your equality?

Comment: Oh! Now I understood.I was unable to comprehend how you were able to use (ab)^n=a^n b^n.Thanks! @AnneBauval